# Angularjs Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error.

The structure of the folder is:

```
AngularJS  
 |---- index.html
 |---- notelist.html
 |---- index.js
```

Moreover, i have added the external link:  angular-route.min.js, but still got the error message. Any idea on it? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="noteApp">
  <head>
    <title>Angular - My Notes</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input.blockInput {
          display: block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My Notes</h1>
    <div ng-controller="Note">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

notelist.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="text" ng-model= "item.Question">
  <input ng-class="{'blockInput': !item.inlineChecked}" type="text" placeholder= "{{item.Note}}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline" ng-model="item.inlineChecked"> Inline
</div>
<button ng-click="add()">New Item</button>
<button ng-click="show()">Sumbit</button>
<div>
    {{json}}
</div>
```

index.js :

```
angular
    .module('noteApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'notelist.html'
            });
    })
    .controller('Note', function($scope){

        $scope.items = [
          { Question: "Question", Note: "enter text..." , inlineChecked: ""}
        ];

        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            inlineChecked: "",
            Question: "Question",
            Note: "enter text..."
          });
        };

        $scope.show = function(){
          $scope.json = $scope.items;
        }
    })
```

Comment: what is the full error stacktrace in the console?  Typically, you give each route its own controller, so I wonder if that has something to do with this.

Comment: what's the meaning of " you give each route its own controller"

Comment: Especially for larger apps, when you are defining routes (the when() blocks), you would say templateUrl:  sometemplate.html, controller: ControllerForThisSpecificView

Answer (score 0):

IvY,

I have created a plunker and your code works fine.

One thing I add in the routeProvider is otherwise.

It also works with you this but its a good practice.

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
      });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GXpKduW6xjorl9ZfJFWl?p=preview

Please let me know if anything.

Comment: That's weird. I checked your plunk and it works, but in mine I had the same error until I added `.run()`.

Comment: thanks! but when click sumbit, the json message does not updated

Answer (score 0):

After your controller definition, add:

```
.run();
```

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mhwRMwj42f3CEUTBG5gL?p=preview)

Whenever you use `.config`, you have to call either run or bootstrap.

Another thing you can do if you get to a point of needing async dependencies is add to the top of your html:

```
window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!'
```

Then, instead of run, call

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['noteApp']);
```

After whatever async loading is completed, call:

```
angular.resumeBootstrap();
```

This is all documented [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), but the `run()` vs auto bootstrapping documentation doesn't appear to be easily accessible on the updated version of angular's documentation. I've recently had to defer bootstrapping for my chrome extension, [new tab redirect](https://github.com/jimschubert/NewTab-Redirect/tree/replacement-ntp/js), and it actually solved some flickering issues I was having with a conditional redirect.

Comment: thanks! but when click sumbit, the json message does not updated

Comment: On plunker? The submit button display the json, but angular provides two way binding, so all typing or adding of notes shows immediately.